# Using thumbnailer in application wrapped as SNAP package

Tags: snap

I'm trying to snap my application currently available for phone and touch as click package. My application use thumbnailer but that fails with permission error running as snap:

```
could not retrieve client config: "An AppArmor policy prevents this sender from sending this message to this recipient; type=\"method_call\", sender=\":1.215\" (uid=1000 pid=15939 comm=\"./usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/bin/qmlscene -I /sn\") interface=\"com.canonical.Thumbnailer\" member=\"ClientConfig\" error name=\"(unset)\" requested_reply=\"0\" destination=\"com.canonical.Thumbnailer\" (uid=1000 pid=15963 comm=\"/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/thumbnailer/thumbnailer-\")" (using default values)
```

and next ...

```
Thumbnailer: RequestImpl::dbusCallFinished(): D-Bus error: An AppArmor policy prevents this sender from sending this message to this recipient; type="method_call", sender=":1.215" (uid=1000 pid=15939 comm="./usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/bin/qmlscene -I /sn") interface="com.canonical.Thumbnailer" member="GetArtistArt" error name="(unset)" requested_reply="0" destination="com.canonical.Thumbnailer" (uid=1000 pid=15963 comm="/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/thumbnailer/thumbnailer-")
```

My snapcraft.yml look like the following:

```
confinement: strict

apps:
  noson-app:
    command: noson-launch
    plugs: [unity7, opengl, home, network, network-bind, content]

parts:
  noson-app:
    source: https://github.com/janbar/noson-app.git
    source-type: git
    source-branch: master
    plugin: cmake
    configflags: [-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr, -DCLICK_MODE=off]
    build-packages:
      - build-essential
      - cmake
      - gettext
      - intltool
      - qtbase5-dev
      - qttools5-dev
      - qttools5-dev-tools
      - qtdeclarative5-dev
      - qtdeclarative5-dev-tools
    stage-packages:
      - ubuntu-sdk-libs
      - qtubuntu-desktop
      - qtmir-desktop
      - mir-graphics-drivers-desktop
      - qmlscene
      - qml-module-qtsysteminfo
      - qml-module-qt-labs-settings
      - qml-module-qtmultimedia
      - qtdeclarative5-ubuntu-content1
      - qtdeclarative5-particles-plugin
      - qtdeclarative5-qtmultimedia-plugin
      - qtdeclarative5-qtquick2-plugin
      - qtdeclarative5-ubuntu-thumbnailer0.1
      - qtdeclarative5-ubuntu-ui-toolkit-plugin
      - qtdeclarative5-window-plugin
      - thumbnailer-service
      - suru-icon-theme
      - ubuntu-mobile-icons
```

Any help in solving this would be greatly appreciated!